# AngularJS: Why I can't print a model variable directly (instead of using $modelValue property)?

Tags: angularjs

In my view I have this form:

```
<form name="form1">
    <input name="msg" id="msg" ng-model="form_data.msg">
</form>
```

In my controller I get the content of the input by

```
var message= $scope.form1.msg;
```

however when I insert some text (e.g. "test_abc") and try to print the contentof the input (within the controller), I get an object instead of the actual value. In fact

```
console.log(messageToSend);
```

gives this output

> [DEBUG] message >>: [object Object]
>       controllers.js:646 Object {$viewValue: "test_abc", $modelValue: "test_abc", $$rawModelValue: "test_abc", $validators: Object, $asyncValidators: Object…}

Of course I can just get $modelValue, but I noticed that (sometimes) I can work with the model value (just by using $scope.modelVarName) it instead of printing it.
Sorry if this is quite vague but I can't find a concrete example right now.

However, just to sum up, I need to understand: **is there a way (other than using .$modelValue property) to retrieve (within the controller) a model variable defined (in a form within a view)?**

Comment: Why don't you use `$scope.form_data.msg` to get value from input? Or maybe the question is not very clear for me.

Comment: you may be right. I will check out it tonight. I'm not sure whether I pasted the wrong code or made that error in the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<input name=msg ng-model="form_data.msg">` with this markup the value of the input will be updated in the controller scope's `form_data.msg` property. [`form_data` is an object].

Angular will update the validation related info of the input field in `form1.msg` of controller's scope. Here `form1` is the name of the form and `msg` is the name of the message. **This is not the actual model**. Your actual model is `form_data.msg`. `form1.msg` will contain the validation related information.

If you want to print the model use `form_data.msg` not `form1.msg`

Comment: I may have made this error indeed. I will try this tonight.

Comment: can you please just clarify the validation thing? I don't get the link between using form.something in the ng-model directive and using $error to show errors (which I use indeed)

Comment: To display the error messages which are the result of validation use details of `$scope._formName_._inputName.` object. To use the input element's value use `$socpe._modelVar_` where `_modelVar_` is the `ng-model` attribute value.

Answer (score 0):

I use your code in jsfiddle and it worked, with a little changes, I just define app and use

```
{{form1.msg}}
```

to print the value.

Here's the jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/diegounanue/5bbkmk3m/

Comment: I'm using Angular Material framework which as far as I know handles the label through the model, but doesn't allow to use <label> within the input. I'm not sure (I will try later) but I think so since basically <input> tag is not closed (and therefore can't include other elements) in the examples they provide